# Different arrangements of people sitting in chairs.

Tags: combinatorics

Thanks in advance for reading my question. I'm meant to solve this as a generalization case whenever there are empty spaces.

Let $k,\ k \geqslant 100$ be the number of people who have just arrived to listen to Dr. K's lecture. The number of empty chairs after everyone sits down is $k -9k/10$. In how many ways the class be arranged after everyone sits down?

Comment: The formula is odd.  you say the number of empty seats is $.1\times k$, yes?  So if more people show up there are more empty seats?

Comment: Yes, it's kind of odd. Assuming they'd getting a bigger room for every iteration of this problem and everyone enters at the same time, I think it's valid.

Comment: Well, makes me think something is wrong.  And what does it mean to "arrange" the class?  Do you just mean "specify the set of empty seats"?  Well, you have $k+.1k=1.1k$ seats all in all so the answer is $\binom {1.1k}{.1k}$.  But I seriously doubt this is the intended answer.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. What I meant is "In how many ways the students can sit"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fMIDiTe.png For example, this specific set has 4 people and 6 seats. Let the 2 last seats be empty, this would give $4!$. But then again, other empty seats can be chosen over the last one. I'm having troubles in generalising this.
As for the question, yes. There are 1.1k chairs.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331394/possible-seeting-arrangments-given-number-of-people-and-number-of-chairs-chair?rq=1

I guess I found something